# Design pattern for connecting between data

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Suppose that I have two groups of data, group A is a list of signals, group B is a list of messages. One message in group B can use many signals in group A. And vice versa, one signal in A can be used by many messages in B. 
Is there any design pattern for this case?

In an example code, Ш see that each message object includes a vector of object `SignalInMessage`, and each signal object includes a vector of object `MessageOfSignal`, and they use derived class `Connection` for connecting data?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is on-topic for stackoverflow. Feels more suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the data static? Will it change over time? What if a message goes while it's being used by a signal? Why not have something in the middle to get messages or signals - if they are shared pointers, then they will hand around while used even if removed from the vectors.

Comment: @doctorlove. data is not static, and messages and signals are stored in two seperate groups. And message uses signal,but signal does not use message.

Comment: shared_ptr FTW then